# Spring Cloud Gateway RouteLocator for SOAP message

Tags: java, soap, spring-cloud

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud Gateway to build a routing service for our system, which is using SOAP protocol. I'd like to create RouteLocator that routing request depend on the value of a field in soap message body, for example every request with msg value is John are routed to a specific service.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.viettel.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:sayHello>
         <msg>John</msg>
      </ser:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

In SPG document, I found [Query Route Predicate Factory](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.0.0.M8/single/spring-cloud-gateway.html#_query_route_predicate_factory) for routing depend on REST query param. How can I do the same with SOAP xml message?

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue - ? Do spring cloud gateway support's proxying soap endpoint ?